# Does the entire scope path need to match for variable reuse in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is the variable `Test` shared in these two scenarios?

```py
with tf.name_scope("ns1"):
  with tf.variable_scope("vs1"):
    var = tf.get_variable("Test", [1,2,3])

with tf.name_scope("ns2"):
  with tf.variable_scope("vs1", reuse=True):
    var = tf.get_variable("Test", [1,2,3])
```

and

```py
with tf.name_scope("ns1"):
  with tf.variable_scope("vs1"):
    var = tf.get_variable("Test", [1,2,3])

with tf.variable_scope("vs1", reuse=True):
  var = tf.get_variable("Test", [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the variable is shared. In general, name_scope does *not* influence variable names, only variable_scope does (but yes, the whole prefix of variable_scopes must match). I think that it is reasonable to try and not use name_scope at all, it can be confusing when mixed with variable_scope. Also note that you set reuse=True -- if the variable were not shared, you'd get an error. That's why it's there, so you can be sure it's shared.

Comment: Thanks! Is `reuse=True` only used after the first instantiation of the variables?